# Trigger specific Jenkins job when multiple repos specified in jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I created separate Jenkins jobs for each of the three github repositories (app1, app2, and app3).
Then there's the deployment and test repositories.

> ```
> app1 repo(with webhook enabled) => app1 JenkinsJob
> app2 repo(with webhook enabled) => app2 JenkinsJob
> app3 repo(with webhook enabled) => app3 JenkinsJob
> deployment repo(webhook NOT enabled)
> test repo(webhook NOT enabled)
> ```

Below is the jenkinsfile of app1.(Only GIT_REPO_URL1 differs for app2 & app3).

```
pipeline {
    environment {
        GIT_REPO_URL1 = 'https://github.com/app1.git'
        GIT_REPO_URL2 = 'https://github.com/deployment.git'
        GIT_REPO_URL3 = 'https://github.com/test.git'
        GIT_REPO_AUTH_CRED = 'abcdefg-123123-321123-qwead-asdqwe123'
    }   agent any
    stages {
        stage('GitClone1') {
            steps {
                checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: 'refs/heads/master']], extensions: [[$class: 'SubmoduleOption', disableSubmodules: false, parentCredentials: true, recursiveSubmodules: false, reference: '', trackingSubmodules: false]], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: "${GIT_REPO_AUTH_CRED}", url: "${GIT_REPO_URL1}"]]])
                echo '========++++++++ GitClone Completed ========++++++++'
            }
        }
        stage('GitClone2') {
            steps {
                checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: 'refs/heads/master']], extensions: [[$class: 'SubmoduleOption', disableSubmodules: false, parentCredentials: true, recursiveSubmodules: false, reference: '', trackingSubmodules: false]], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: "${GIT_REPO_AUTH_CRED}", url: "${GIT_REPO_URL2}"]]])
                echo '========++++++++ GitClone Completed ========++++++++'
            }
        }
        stage('GitClone3') {
            steps {
                checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: 'refs/heads/master']], extensions: [[$class: 'SubmoduleOption', disableSubmodules: false, parentCredentials: true, recursiveSubmodules: false, reference: '', trackingSubmodules: false]], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: "${GIT_REPO_AUTH_CRED}", url: "${GIT_REPO_URL3}"]]])
                echo '========++++++++ GitClone Completed ========++++++++'
            }
        }
    } }
```

Code delivery on app1/app2/app3 is triggering app1/app2/app3 jenkins jobs respectively.

**Now issue is,** when i push a code change to https://github.com/deployment.git or https://github.com/test.git repositories, Jenkins pipelines for app1, app2, and app3 are automatically triggered.

Expected Fix:
The app jenkins job should be triggered by only code delivery to the app repos.

Comment: Please add more info on your current triggering mechanism.

Comment: @NoamHelmer In terms of triggering mechanism, 
1. Github side, Added Hook url https://jenkins-endpoint.com/github-webhook/,
2. Jenkins Side, Checked "GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling" option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it by adding **changelog: false** and **poll: false** to the code.

The complete list is provided below.
Someone might find this beneficial.

```
checkout changelog: false, poll: false, scm: [$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/master']], extensions: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: "${GIT_CRED}", url: "${GIT_REPO_URL2}"]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

The `GitSCM` class in the [checkout](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-scm-step/) step has a dedicated additional behavior for disabling triggers for the configured repository:

> **Don't trigger a build on commit notifications**
>
> If checked, this repository will be ignored when the notifyCommit-URL is accessed regardless of if the repository matches or not.

This attribute can be configured in pipeline by using extension with class `IgnoreNotifyCommit`.
So to achieve what you want just add this configuration to the `checkout` options of each repository that should not trigger the job.
For example:

```groovy
 checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[...]], extensions: [[$class: 'IgnoreNotifyCommit'],[$class: 'SubmoduleOption',...]], userRemoteConfigs: [[...]]])
```

Comment: Not working. 
updated like below for GitClone2 and GitClone3. But when i deliver code change to GIT_REPO_URL2 or GIT_REPO_URL3, app1 jenkins job is triggering.
 checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/master']], extensions: [[$class: 'IgnoreNotifyCommit']], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: "${GIT_REPO_AUTH_CRED}", url: "${GIT_REPO_URL3}"]]]).